Undeclared identifier when it is obviously declared
I have a code like the snippet below:
#include <map>
//using namespace std;

int main(){
constexpr int defval = -2e9;
struct defint
{
    int i = -defval;
    bool operator==(const int& j) { return i == j; }
    defint& operator=(int x) { i = x; return *this; }
};
std::map<char, defint> ci;
ci['a'] = 0;
}

This gives me C2065: 'defval': undeclared identifier at the line int i = defval;, but the defval is obviously declared before. How do I use the declared const in a struct or class so that the compiler sees it as it should? defval is not declared anywhere before the definition in the snippet and the error appears only when I add the line that makes use of the map, which is ci['a'] = 0;. The compiler I am using is the one from MSVS 2022 with the C++20 standard.

Works here. We need a [mcve] something that can be copy/pasted and used to reproduce the said issue/problem/error.

Which compiler are you using ? it works with MSVC, Clang and GCC https://godbolt.org/z/KsPdGdvsq

Mention the compiler version and the c++ standard you're using. Also which command are you using to build your project.

And whether the file was saved before being compiled and ran. And whether the code was recompiled at all. That always trips up a few Intro students every time.

Check to see if there are any unexpected control characters in your source code file.  I've seen that be the cause of puzzling compilation problems. Including Unicode homoglyphs in source code as being a head-scratcher.

@Eljay like p and р.Or even worse, c and с, because they are on same key.

One thing I can say that defval isn't statically initialized. 2e9 is a double literal, not an int.

Try checking if defval is already declared earlier as a #define macro

You should post is code that is minimal, complete and produces the error described. Code like the code you really have doesn't cut it, because inevitably when you cut down your code for posting you remove the thing that caused the error in the first place.

You may want to declare defval as constexpr int.  This tells the compiler that the variable can be treated as a compile time constant.

@ThomasMatthews constexpr int did not help.

@Swift-FridayPie changing it to an int does not help really. When I set it to be, say, -20, the same error comes up.

@user12002570 I updated the question specifying the compiler and standard versions I am currently using.

@RedRidingHood Try building your project in a new separate directory. You might be building your old project due to some reason. Delete the current build completely and create new folder and files and write sme code from scratch and build this new project and see if you get the same error.

In MSVS, try doing a "Build Clean"  (the specifics of how to do that depends on version of MSVS, but is typically done in the menus via something like "Build -> Clean" or "Build -> Clean Solution" or "Build -> Clean Only").   Then build your entire project (you will find all source files in your project will recompile).      I suggest this because it is not uncommon for MSVS (or other build tools) to lose track of what it has compiled and what it hasn't - with a consequence of error messages that don't align with the (version of the) source code.

using defint in template std::map combined with locally defined defval variable and defint  is what breaks it. Afaik, they can be only global for portability. Context of std::map should be able to be able to access defval to generate inline constructor for defint

This seems to be a msvc bug and the program is well-formed.
Workarounds
There are two ways to solve this. Basically, msvc seems to have issue with defval not having static storage duration. So the ways just give defval static storage duration.
Solution 1
Here we add static constexpr to defval
int main(){
    //--------vvvvvv--------------------->added static
    constexpr static int defval = -2e9;
    //same code as before below
}

Working demo
Solution 2
Another way of giving defval a static storage duration is by making it global:
//no need to write static explicitly at global scope for constexpr variable
constexpr int defval = -2e9;
int main(){
   
    //same code as before here
}


Here is the newly submitted msvc bug:
MSVC rejects use of constexpr local variable when used with std::map

Wow, thank you very much, man. Do you know how soon will the compiler fix be available?

The downvotes are probably because initially it was not a complete reproducible example.

@RedRidingHood MSVC usually takes a long time but I've also seen some of the bugs being fixed withing days! For example, I once submitted one msvc bug and it was fixed in 3 or 4 days. So it depends what priority they set for the bug. You can use one of the workarounds till then. You're welcome. And I don't understand why someone would downvote an answer when the question was not originally reproducible and also when the answer is useful. But, again I know our reason for downvote here is just speculation.

bug is grandfathered.  MSVC shows similar behaviour as early as 2017 version. Their read of the situation is that a local non-static const variable isn't compile-time which is problematic with their template information.
